# Trying to lock a custom control, but having problems when more than one of the control in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a custom control that I load on to a page three times.

The custom control consists of a text box and a custom date picker control.

I am trying to lock the date picker control for all.

I tried the following code in my control.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    debugger;
    var mySelector = '#' + $('[id$=\'_SignatureNonPoliceControl\']', $(this)).attr('id');
    $(mySelector.replace('_SignatureNonPoliceControl', '_SignatureDatePicker_DatePickerControl')).BaseControlPlugin(BaseControlMethodsEnum.SetLocked, true);
});
```

However this only locks the first one and does it three times.

My controls are set out like this

```
            <uc8:SignatureCaptureNonPolice ID="DetaineeSignature" runat="server" Caption = "Person's Signature to Comments " RetainValueWhenDisabled="true" />

            <uc1:GenericDropDownList Caption="Reason For Not Signing " ID="DetaineeReasonNotSignedGenericDropDownList" runat="server" />

            <uc8:SignatureCaptureNonPolice ID="AppropriateAdultSignature" runat="server" Caption = "Appropriate Adults<br />Signature to Comments " RetainValueWhenDisabled="true" />

            <uc8:SignatureCaptureNonPolice ID="InterpreterSignature" runat="server" Caption = "Interpreter's Signature<br />to Comments " RetainValueWhenDisabled="true" />
```

Do I have to use $(this).  I am quite new to this.

Help!

Thanks

Kev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your date pickers have a common class? You could just select on that:

```
$('.className')
```

The other option is to comma separate all of your ID's in one selector:

```
$('#firstID,#secondID,#thirdID')
```

Then I assume you want to apply a locked class to them?

```
$('.className').addClass("locked");
```

And you can check that logic easily by doing stuff like this:

```
if (this.hasClass("locked") {
    // this is locked.
}
```

Read more on selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/